Closed form for recurrence relation involving exponential
I was working with a sequences and got this sequence: $[1,3,8,20,48...]$. I determined this sequence to have the recurrence relation of $a_{i+1}=2a_i+2^{i}$, with $a_0=1$ and due to my lack of knowledge in recurrences and solving them I hope someone can post a closed form for it as I have been unable to find a solution through other means.

Are you familiar with OEIS? You can see search results for your sequence here. However there are a few different results there starting with these numbers, so you may need to produce a few more entries to narrow it down. In any case just given these numbers without any complete definition of the sequence we won't be able to prove anything about it.

Could I ask why you are interested in this recurrence relation? If you are looking for a solution to the recurrence relation $a_{i + 1} = 2a_i + 2^i$, $a_0 = 1$, note that this is a linear, first-order, inhomogeneous recurrence relation.

This sequence arrose when I was doing something similar in nature to Pascal's Triangle. The triangle instead of having 1s along its left diagonal would have a sequence, in this case the integers. Then the the rest of the triangle would be filled out by adding a number to the number to its right and above. Then this sequence arrises as the right diagonal. Here the first couples rows: 1 then 2,3 then 3,5,8, then 4, 7, 12, 20  then 5, 9, 16, 28, 48 and so on.

Consider
$$b_i = a_i - i\cdot 2^{i-1}$$
then
$$b_{i+1}=a_{i+1}-(i+1) \cdot 2^{i} = 2a_i +2^i -i \cdot 2^i -2^i= 2b_{i}$$
From which it can easily be deduced:
$$b_{i+1}=2^{i+1}\cdot b_0=2^{i+1}$$
Therefore,  $$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_i - i\cdot 2^{i-1}=2^i$$
$$\implies\boxed{a_{i} = 2^i + i\cdot 2^{i-1} }$$
This can be proven using induction.

HINT: You can convert this to a homogeneous linear second order equation as follows,
$$
\frac{a_{i+1}-2a_i}{a_{i+2}-2a_{i+1}}=\frac{2^i}{2^{i+1}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Can you take it from here? Alternatively, you could assume a solution of the form $f_n=a_n+A2^n$ and attempt to find A such that you are left with a homogeneous equation for $f_n$.
